# Display not updating after object is added to LocalStorage array using Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have a drag and drop feature to compile an array of images. In order to show what has been added to the array, I have them stored in localstorage and set as a variable named selectedGallery, which is then iterated out in the display, but is not updating when I drop a new image in. The new object is pushed to localstorage, but using an observable subject, the changes seem to take place in the application tab but are not updating on the view.

**.html**

```
<label>Gallery Images</label>
<div class="gallery">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let image of selectedGallery">
      <img class="placeholder" [src]="imageUrl + image.url" alt="selected image thumbnail">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

So here I am iterating out the images from selectedGallery and when I manually refresh the page, the image array is updated. I have run a quick console.log on the following which is called on ngOnInit:

**.component.ts**

```
this.watchStorage().subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
        this.selectedGallery = data;
        console.log(this.selectedGallery);//returns undefined :/
  }
)
```

this only logs undefined.

here is a little more context:

**.component.ts**

```
private storageSubject = new Subject<string>();

watchStorage(): Observable<any>{
  return this.storageSubject.asObservable();
}

this.configService.uploadImage(imageUpload)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response) {
          imageFile = response.data;
          if (localStorage) {
          var selectedImages;
          if (!localStorage['selectedImages']) selectedImages = [];
          else selectedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage['selectedImages']);
          if (!(selectedImages instanceof Array)) selectedImages = [];
          selectedImages.push(imageFile);
          localStorage.setItem('selectedImages', JSON.stringify(selectedImages));
          this.storageSubject.next('image');
         }
      }});

ngOnInit() {
  this.watchStorage().subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      this.selectedGallery = data.result;
      console.log(this.selectedGallery);//this logs undefined :/
    }
  )
}
```

this as it is, doesn't update selectedGallery in the view and I'm not sure why.

Has anyone had this problem before?

scratching one's head right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are emitting a string `this.storageSubject.next('image');`. Data value is very likely string 'image' and it has no field result.

Why not emit `selectedImages`?

Comment: I spotted that just. I have altered to emit: this.storageSubject.next(selectedImages); I have removed .result from the watchStorage() response and it now works. I had it in my head that I need to define the new object as it is written in the ngfor loop. But this works now, thank you for spotting that.